# Number of formal parameters is larger than the number of actual parameters

Tags: abap

So when I try to compile (activate), the compiler throws this error message:

```
Different number of parameters in FORM and PERFORM (routine: 
CALL_CALCULATE_TAX_ITEM, number of formal parameters: 7, number of
actual parameters: 6)
```

It refers to the line 169 in the include LJ_1B_NFE_INF3B, where there is this statement:

```
PERFORM call_calculate_tax_item
                         USING
                              ls_rbkpv
                              ls_drseg
                              ls_j_lbaa
                              ls_lfa1
                              ls_xmlpo
                              abap_true
                          CHANGING
                              et_bapiret2[].
```

Here is the form code:

```
FORM call_calculate_tax_item
                USING    ls_rbkpv TYPE mrm_rbkpv
                         ls_drseg TYPE mmcr_drseg
                         ls_j_1baa TYPE j_1baa
                         ls_lfa1   TYPE lfa1
                         ls_xmlpo  TYPE ty_xmlpo_ext        "1843823
                         lv_get_conditions TYPE flag        "2142110
                CHANGING et_bapiret2 TYPE bapirettab.
```

So, it's obvious that there are 7 parameters both in PERFORM and FORM, why does the compiler say that there are only 6 actual parameters?

Thanks and sorry for broken English.

Comment: Looks like there is only a partial implementation of a note 2142110 or you have not activated all the dependecies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I will check that note right know.

Comment: When you click Activate, and a popup comes up (with all inactive objects), make sure that all lines are marked, so they will be activated at the same time (just in case if the FORM and the PERFORM are not in the same program (include)).

Comment: Re implemented the note 2142110 and the issue was solved thanks!

Comment: @Jagger could you convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Usually such problems result from a not fully implemented SAP Note or not activating all the changes made by the note at the very same time.

In your case I see that either SAP Note 2142110 is not fully implemented or some of the changes resulting from the implementation of it have not been activated.

Comment: "or not activating all the changes [...] at the very same time" : this happens when the FORM and the PERFORM are not in the same source code unit (include), both includes must be activated at the same time. This may not only happen with notes, but also with custom code.